# Can npm packages contain any programming language?

Tags: javascript, bash, npm, module, package

Say for instance you wanted to publish an npm package with bash scripts for certain tasks is that a.) allowed by npm package registry? and b.) is there a way to execute a bash script from within the logic of a specific javascript file? Maybe using child-processes or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

well you can use exec() from child_process https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/